# pdfgetpage MediaBox mixes up width and height

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

When I run below command

```
gs -dNODISPLAY -dBATCH -dQUIET -dNOSAFER -sFileName=${filename} \
  -c "FileName (r) file runpdfbegin 1 1 pdfpagecount {pdfgetpage /MediaBox get {=print ( ) print} forall (\\n) print} for quit"
```

I get width for height and height for width. I get below output:

```
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
0.0 0.0 4272.0 2848.0
```

where 4272.0 is height of pdf but it shows as width. For other pdfs it works as expected. Is this pdf somehow rotated? How can detect and fix it?

Edit: I also found that pdfinfo shows each page is rotated by 90 degrees in this pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You probably also want the /Rotate value from the Page dictionary. Modifying your example:

"FileName  (r) file runpdfbegin 1 1 pdfpagecount {pdfgetpage dup /MediaBox get {=print ( ) print} forall dup /Rotate known { /Rotate get (  Rotate: ) print =print } { pop } ifelse  (\n) print} for quit"

Also note that for Ghostscript past 9.50 SAFER is the default, so you may need to use the  "--permit-file-read=___" option on your command line for your file.